# Virtualbox - how to move virtual machine to another PC

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

Can't move virtual machine to another PC, have copied turnkey-core-2009.10-2-hardy-x86.vmdk to folder .VirtualBox -> HardDisks.

Created new machine, pointed to copied file.

Started created machine and it drops this error after a while(5 mins)

[image: Screen Shot]

As I understand, there is some difference in uniq ids, but how can I handle it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use vdi image format and have no problem migrating from one computer to another.  I would either look into using vdi format, or correcting the uuid in /etc/fstab.  uuid can be determined with the blkid command from the command line.

Comment: Can you please be a bit more specific about changing uuids on Windows? As i understand it should be edited inside xml config, but how to get correct uuid?

Comment: not on windows...inside the vm.

Comment: oh, right in console after error occured?

Comment: Have entered vm setting and checked some setting and it worked. lol :)

Comment: upon further examination it seems there are 2 approaches...modify the VM xml to match your original(or copy that too) or fix your VM contents.  either way

Answer (score 0):

Moving the disk image file to another location and creating a new vm and pointing it to the copied disk image should do the trick. Alternatively, you can export the machine and then import it in the other PC. This is not the typical way but at least the hypervisor will generate "the same settings", as much as possible, for you. (It helps if you easily forget things!).